# Right web api route but goes to wrong request url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-web-api

on developer tool: http://localhost:xxx/Event/api/events/1 <--- 404

right route: http://localhost:7688/api/events/1

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            var settings = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
            settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );  
        }
    }
```

my js

```
 @section scripts{
        <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#events .js-join").on("click", function () {

                        $.ajax({
                            url: "api/events/" + $(this).attr("data-event-id"),
                            method: "PUT",
                            success: function () {
                                alert("Saved successfully");
                            }
                        });
                    });


                });
        </script>

    }
```

I am able to use postman to go to the right route and I've verified that my api is working.

Comment: let me know if you need more info

Comment: Add a leading `/` - `url: "/api/events/" + ...`

Comment: silly me! thank you for that @stephen muecke saved my day

Comment: If you don't add the leading `/`, then the browser appends to url supplied to the current page. leading `/` tells the browser to append it to the root.